# Block Check Character (BCC) error burst detection

Tags: networking, error-detection, parity

Disclaimer: Not homework!

## Problem

I've been reading up on BCC error detection for my networks course and have got a bit confused over one particular explanation in some of the slides.

## Given Information

We are provided the following explanation:

```
    | r |m6 |m5 |m4 |m3 |m2 |m1 |m0
------------------------------------
w0  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
w1  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1
w2  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
w3  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
w4  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
-----------------------------------
BCC | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0
```

- Let n = row length (n=8 in this case)
- Remember, not all bits in a burst need be in error, just the first and last
- BCC copes with (n+1)-bit bursts (9-bit bursts in this case)

## Question

Could someone please explain to me how this is the case/how it works?

## Example Problem

(Seen in a past paper)
For example given a diagram as above, how many burst bits can be reliably detected in a block? Explain your answer.

Any help greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT: Added reference slide**

[image: The (only) slide form my lecture notes on this topic]

Comment: Peter, can you please post your reference? From your definition above, the maximum burst length is n. BCC is the summation module 2 of all the words (bytes) of your message. If you have an even number of errors in any bit position (column), BCC will not help you identifying an error condition.

Comment: @guga I have added the reference slide from my notes. It is literally just this one slide I can't understand and there is nothing very related either side of it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter, the column `r` contains the summation module 2 of `m0 ... m6`, so any odd number of errors in a word is detectable (`r` is called *parity bit*).

Similarly, each ***BCC*** bit is computed by the summation module 2 of the column, that's why ***BCC*** is also called ***longitudinal redundancy check***.

Now, to have a burst error that is **not** detectable (meaning, the coding scheme failed its purpose), an even number of errors is necessary ***both*** in rows and columns. So, to find the ***shortest*** error burst that fails to be detected, you have to have 2 bit errors in one word (so the parity bit doesn't detect) and another 2 bit errors in the following word (shortest burst) in a way that the errors are column aligned (so the ***BCC*** doesn't catch the condition). This construct requires a burst length of ***n+2*** bits as represented in the diagram by the red color. So, any error burst that is less than or equal to ***n+1*** bits in length can be detected by this method.

Note that there are **many** other longer error burst combinations that are detectable by ***BCC***, but when you are talking about *error detection capability* of a coding scheme, you specify the worst case scenario.

I hope this helps!